# How do I style a div in between a Header and Footer to always take up 100% of the remaining space?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to create a header and footer for my website. Both the header and footer are static so they can move accordingly if the user is on mobile to ensure the best visibility of the middle content. My question becomes how do I set the middle content to always take up 100% of the remaining space? The header and footer aren't always the same height because Bootstrap navbars are responsive. So the footer might be 50 pixels high on the desktop but in mobile it will be something like 62 pixels high because it stacked the footer content (text). Here's the code that I have:

```
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <div class="navbar-brand">
                            Brand
                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left tabs">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><div>
                                        <label class="IconText">Home</label>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div>
                                        <label class="IconText">Settings</label>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div>
                                        <label class="IconText">About</label>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="#"><div>
                                        <label class="IconText">Contact</label>
                                </div></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Header End -->

        <!-- Middle Content -->
        <div id="background" style="margin-top: -20px;">
            <div class="mainContent">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Middle Content End -->

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <p><label id="Label" class="navbar-text"></label></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer End -->
</body>
```

And here's my attempt at the CSS. I've been browsing this website and others for a while trying everything that I found but nothing seems to work.

```
.mainContent {
            height: calc(100% - 120px); /* IE9+ and future browsers */
            height: -moz-calc(100% - 120px); /* Firefox */
            height: -webkit-calc(100% - 120px); /* Chrome, Safari */
        }
        #background {
            background : #000000 url("./Images/black_background.jpg") no-repeat bottom left;
            overflow:hidden;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

In desktop mode the Header takes up 70px and the Footer takes up 50px so that's where the 120px in the mainContent style section comes from but again the Header and Footer sizes are responsive.

Comment: And how exactly are the header and footer responsive? If the height is set with percentages, just subtract that ?

Comment: Use the same responsive css that makes the header/footer responsive to size the content.

Comment: If the header and footer can only have a few different sizes, then you can set the height of the content with a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Otherwise, I suspect you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure how Bootstrap sets the size of the Header and Footer. I'm trying to dig through the CSS for it but it's like 5K lines of code. From what I'm finding headers and footers are simply navbars. The .Navbar section only lists of min-height of 50px. There really isn't a percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An age old question, with a good answer/starting point here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/.

It's not bootstrap specific, so you may have to hammer some stuff into place, but the gist of it is there.